# cannot Copy file from google cloud bucket to VM instance

Tags: permissions, copy, cloud, transfer

I am trying to transfer file from cloud bucket to VM instance.

I connected to VM instance by SSH, And used gsutil code like this :

gsutil cp gs://[bucket name]/[file name] /home

and then error was occur

Copying gs://huji/final-project-deep-learning-19-tf.tar...
OSError: Permission denied. GiB]

So I tried this command :

sudo gsutil cp gs://[bucket name]/[file name] /home

And then, downloading completed.

Copying gs://huji/final-project-deep-learning-19-tf.tar...
| [1 files][  1.7 GiB/  1.7 GiB]   76.2 MiB/s

but I cannot find any files and the disk volume hasn't changed.
Can anybody explain why this happens and how to copy files from cloud? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a service account [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-create-gcloud):

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts create transfer --description "transfer" --display-name "transfer"
   ```
2. Set up a new instance to run as a service account:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create instance --service-account transfer@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
   ```

> For example, the scope for full access to Cloud Storage is
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control. The alias for
>   this scope is storage-full

3. SSH to the VM instance:

   ```
   gcloud beta compute --project "my-project" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "instance"
   ```
4. Copy the files :

   ```
   gsutil cp gs://bucket/file.csv .
   ```
5. List the files:

   ```
   ls
   file.csv
   ```